# Can I use Javacard without reader and physical card?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, reader, emv

I'm working on a project related to smartcard security, and I wanted to conduct some tests. But I cannot acquire a card reader to test with at the moment. Is there a way to use Javacard toolkits without having a physical card and card reader? (e.g. an online library that can completely emulate a card without using a physical card reader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaCard SDK distributed by Oracle includes an emulated card that can be launched as an Eclipse plug-in.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javacard-sdk-downloads.html

I haven't used it for a long time now, but it was extremely useful for debugging some applications.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [jCardSim](https://jcardsim.org/) project which simulates JCRE classes -- see their [Quick Start Guide](https://jcardsim.org/docs/quick-start-guide-simulator-api).

This project is great for "dry" prototyping and unit testing of Java Card projects.